# WhatsApp background running system

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, whatsapp

I am interested to know how WhatsApp runs in Android background system even after cleaning it from ram cleaner.
I made an Android app in which I started service and broadcast receiver but when I cleaned it using ram cleaner, both got stopped. Even sometimes push notifications are also not received when app is not running in background.
So, I just wanted to know that how WhatsApp manages all this. I am just giving an example as WhatsApp because I found its system amusing.

Comment: Try using AlarmManager.Which invokes your service in a timely manner.As you specify,when you start your service.

Comment: I used it to start my service at specific interval but when I cleaned app it didn't start after then.

Comment: I guess it got cleaned too in that.

Comment: You want to call AlarmManager setting in a while loop or in an onDestroy function.But don't stick on onDestroy,as it is a maybe call.

Comment: @jarvis: have got any solution because i am facing same problem  with Mi4i. Lollipop.

Comment: No. Still don't know how other apps work fine even after cleaning @AmolDale.

Answer (score 3):

If you return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`, the system will automatically restart the service once it determines that it is not resource strained. Which means it will probably restart immediately if you have killed it using an app killer.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: But it will only restart if Android has killed that service due to lack of memory or any other reason. Not if I have killed that service using available ram cleaner apps.

Comment: Well, maybe you're using some app that I don't have experience with. But I highly doubt that any app will have control over the Android system level behavior.

Comment: Even when I use my Xiomi Mi4i inbuilt app cleaner, it gets stopped